# How to change the path of displaytag.properties?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, displaytag

Currently i have placed the Displaytag.properties in 'src' directory, and it is working fine. Is it posssible to have this file on some different location like src/comp/bre/sub/config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for the [DisplayTag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/10/configuration.html) library:

> For the whole web application, create
>   a custom properties file named
>   "displaytag.properties" and place it
>   in the application classpath.
>   Displaytag will use the locale of the
>   request object to determine the locale
>   of the property file to use; if the
>   key required does not exist in the
>   specified file, the key will be loaded
>   from a more general property file.

So in your case make sure your build scripts (or IDE) copy your `displaytag.properties` file from `src/comp/bre/sub/config` the onto the classpath.

In an *IDE* this is normally as simple as specifying that a particular directory contains source code.  In *ANT* just make sure the `displaytag.properties` file ends up in your `/WEB-INF/classes`.

Answer (score 0):

Find the code which loads this properties file and add the new path. You can also place it in a folder yourProject/src/resources/ and add it to the classpath. Therefore, your properties file will be placed in the binary folder once the code will be compiled.